# RavenDB sum of a count

Tags: indexing, ravendb

I'm trying to do a sum of a count of a child collection in a Raven query.  It is returning a count of 0.  If I use the same LINQ on the object directly, then it works with a count of 2.

Is this query possible with auto-indexing on Raven?  If I need to create a map-reduce index, can someone help me with that?

```
        [TestMethod]
        public void CalculateUserClickCount()
        {
            var db = new EmbeddableDocumentStore { RunInMemory = true };
            db.Initialize();
            using (var session = db.OpenSession())
            {
                var user = new User();
                var product = new Product();
                product.Clicks.Add(new Click());
                product.Clicks.Add(new Click());
                user.Storefront.EndoProducts.Add(product);
                session.Store(user);
                session.SaveChanges();

                var users = session.Query<User>()
                    .Customize(t => t.WaitForNonStaleResults())
                    .Select(t => new
                    {
                        StoreFrontId = t.Storefront.StorefrontID,
                        itemCount = t.Storefront.EndoProducts.Count,
                        updateDate = t.Storefront.LastUpdateDate,
                        clickCount = t.Storefront.EndoProducts.Sum(r => r.Clicks.Count), // this is improperly set to 0
                        TotalAffiliateRevenue = t.Storefront.SaleReports.Sum(r => r.TotalAffiliateEarnings) // this works
                    })
                    .ToList();

                int clickCount = user.Storefront.EndoProducts.Sum(t => t.Clicks.Count); // this is properly set to 2

                Assert.AreEqual(2, users[0].clickCount);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a map/reduce for this, because you are only operating on a single document at any time.
What you do need it s transform results, most probably, to do this.